# Error while setting device as testdevice in android

Tags: android, admob

I'm using the following code in xml to set my device as a test device:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                         ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, xxxxxxxxx"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
```

I'm running into this error:

```
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'testDevices' in package 'com.itspirits.lifenavigatorlite'
```

I'm including the ads namespace as `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

any suggestion?

Comment: If you have added it, why didn't you include it in your `AdView` definition?

Comment: i've added the namespace in the root element

Comment: Try replacing it by: `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.yourpackage.yourclass"`

Comment: by doing this, I'm getting this error:The ad size and ad unit ID must be set before calling loadAd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new AdMob's `AdView` (included in Google Play Services) doesn't have `testDevices` attribute in XML. Check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdView.html).

You need to add your test devices in the code:

```
AdRequest.Builder adRequestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();
adRequestBuilder.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR);
adRequestBuilder.addTestDevice("xxxxxxxxx");  
adView.loadAd(adRequestBuilder.build());
```

Comment: I added u're code, it apparently works, but still when I'm pressing the ads, it goes to google play

Comment: You mean the ads still work? The test add is not shown? Have you checked that your adding the right device ID?

Comment: Yes, I'm using this String android_id = Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(),
             Secure.ANDROID_ID); to get the device id

Comment: No, it's a separate ID for AdMob. You can find it in logcat.

Comment: It looks like "Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("xxxxx") to get test ads on this device."